# Volume Enclosed Between a Surface and a Plane

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

This is a problem that I came up with that has been driving me crazy. I have not been able to find a solution nor a person who could direct me to one.
The problem is as follows;
Find the volume of the region enclosed by the surfaces on [$-\pi..\pi, -\pi..\pi]$ (These are meant to describe the x and y value ranges, excuse my lack of knowledge on formal math notation)
$$F(x,y)=cos(x)+cos(y)$$
$$G(x,y)=1/2$$
I need to specific, however, that I do not want to find the net volume of this region as 1-These are trigonometric functions with an infinite domain and therefore never reach a truly enclosed area and 2-Selecting a square region as I have will result in an answer of 0.
The volume I want to find in specific is the one enclosed by the plane G(x,y) and F(x,y) where F(x,y) lies above the plane. Below are some pictures to illustrate this.[image: 3dplotview]

[image: boundary view]

This problem is a bit above my current math knowledge, but I am really itching for a solution/walkthrough on the problem. The biggest obstacle for me is determining how to describe the boundary of the region I need to integrate over. Any help would be much appreciated and I can answer any questions as I know my explanation isn't perfectly clear/formalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it is clear that the region of integration reaches its maximum width when either $x$ or $y$ $=0$. Setting $y=0$,
$$F(x,0)=\cos(x)+\cos(0)$$
Then,
$$F(x,0)=G(x,y) \implies \cos(x)+\cos(0)=\frac{1}{2}$$
Which has solutions at $x=\pm \frac{2\pi}{3}$.
Now let's find the bounds for our $y$ values. So,
$$F(x,y)=G(x,y) \implies \cos(x)+\cos(y)=\frac{1}{2}$$
So then
$$y=\pm \arccos(\frac{1}{2}-\cos(x)).$$
So our integral is
$$\int_{-\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\frac{2\pi}{3}}\int_{-\arccos(\frac{1}{2}-\cos(x))}^{\arccos(\frac{1}{2}-\cos(x))}(\cos(x)+\cos(y)-\frac{1}{2}) \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x \approx 8.26979$$
Computed [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28int%28cos%28x%29%2Bcos%28y%29-1%2F2%2Cy%2C-arccos%281%2F2-cos%28x%29%29%2Carccos%281%2F2-cos%28x%29%29%29%2Cx%2C-2*pi%2F3%2C2*pi%2F3%29)

Comment: I should probably edit in formatted parentheses (```\left(``` and ```\right)```) but it's late and I'm far too lazy.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your question is to find the volume bounded in the "hump" (call it $R$) where $F > G$. This will involve integrating a function with respect to $x$ and $y$ over some region $R$ corresponding to the points where $F > G$. That is, $F(x, y) > G(x, y)$ if and only if $(x, y) \in R$.

To do this, we just need to find what the ranges of $x$ and $y$ are that define the region $R$. We can observe that boundary of $R$ is defined by the relation $\cos (x) + \cos (y) = 1/2$. Note that both $\cos (x)$ and $\cos (y)$ are both at least $-1/2$ for the equality to hold, since $\cos$ takes on values in the range $[-1, 1]$. Thus, $x, y \in [-2\pi/3, 2\pi/3]$.

Let us calculate the volume of the region where $x, y \geq 0$. Note that this constitutes a quarter of the hump (let's call this portion $Q$). As with $R$, the region $Q$ is defined by the inequality $\cos (x) + \cos (y) \geq 1/2$, so for any fixed $x$, $\cos (y)$ can range from $1$ to $1/2 - \cos(x)$, so $y$ can range from $0$ to $\arccos(1/2 - \cos x)$. The volume of the region $H$ is given by the integral
$$\int_H [F(x, y) - G(x, y)] dx dy = \int_0^{2\pi / 3} \int_0^{\arccos(1/2 - \cos x)} [\cos x + \cos y - 1/2] dy dx$$
To get the area of your desired region $R$, you would just have to multiply the result of this integral by four. Unfortunately, this integral does not seem to have a closed-form solution (the $\arccos(1/2 - \cos x)$ causes quite a few problems), so numerical integration seems to be the way to go.